# PhpStorm SFTP error

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to connect via SFTP with PhpStorm to VirtualBox instnace with right credentials which is working right on cli but I get `Connection to ... failed 386` on PhpStorm.

What does this error means?

Comment: Enable extra logging for Deployment; reproduce the error and check the idea.log file

Comment: hi thanks for feedback can you explain how do I enable extra logging for Deployment?

Comment: Yeah... forgot to add the link --sorry about that. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Comment: thanks a lot!! finally I gotted fixed seeing the error dumps

Comment: Would be great if you answer your own question (how you discovered what the error means; what you did to fix it etc) -- it will be very useful to other users who may face the same issue.